# Как ядро определяет процесс для которого получено прерывание?

Tags: linux, kernel, прерывания, ядро

Из книги Таненбаума "Современные операционные системы" я узнал что, к примеру, жесткий диск может обрабатывать поступающие запросы не в том порядке, в котором они переданы, если это позволяет обработать их оптимальнее.

Возник вопрос: Допустим у нас есть процесс A и B, оба они желают считать данные с диска. Процесс A инициирует запрос, планировщик переключает исполнение на процесс B и тот тоже инициирует запрос на чтение с того же диска. Теперь диск говорит контроллеру прерываний что он выполнил запрос для B. Как теперь ядро понимает что нужно сообщить именно процессу B что для него готовы данные, а не A. Где эта информация хранится или передается?
Везде написано просто что вызывается обработчик прерывания соответствующий линии, где выставлено прерывание, но совершенно нет информации как при этом происходит определение процесса для которого готова информация.

Comment: Такие устройства в ответе передают обратно вместе с данными (и проч. статусной инфой) и ID запроса, на который отвечают. Вот по этому ID система и находит цепочку управляющих блоков, которая ведет к процессу, инициировавшему запрос.

Comment: В ответе кому? По какому каналу идет передача статусной информации и ID запроса? Ведь линия прерывания это по сути 0/1 для оповещения что устройство выполнило какой-то запрос или по ней можно прямо данные перегнать?
Не подскажите где можно поподробнее прочитать хоть с каким-нибудь примером?

Comment: По линиям HBA (Host Bus Adapter) т.е. по каналу передачи данных, естественно  (по SAS, SATA, FC, SCSI, USB или что у Вас там), а не по линии прерывания.

Answer (score 5):

### Упорядочивание очереди

**Магнитные жесткие диски выполняют быстрее такие запросы, данные которых лежат ближе к считывающей головке**

Да, это позволяет эффективнее использовать перемещение головки по диску . Подобные действия, например реализует аппаратный алгоритм NCQ, ведь зачем 500 раз крутить головку, последовательно перебирая очередь, когда можно взять данные которые ближе? Это минимизирует количество перемещений головок и ожидание нужного сектора на треке. Существуют аппаратные алгоритмы и программные алгоритмы реализации упорядочивания.

---

### Пример из реальной жизни

Пассажиры набиваются в лифт на первом этаже и нажимают те этажи которые им нужны, лифт едет последовательно по номеру этажей, не различая разницы между тем кто нажал первый или последний, эффективно обслуживая текущую очередь. А если бы он обслуживал сначала тех, кто нажал первый, представьте сколько лишних километров бы наматывал лифт? Сначала на 6, потом на 2 и т.д..

---

Вы удивитесь, но есть диспетчеры ввода-вывода, **которые могут объединить два ваших запроса в один**, но вы об этом даже не узнаете. Диспетчер ввода вывода делает все, чтобы оптимизировать время работы на запрос и кол-во выполняемой работы.

### Жесткий диск и операционная система

Система ввода-вывода многоуровневая. Все ваши запросы обслуживает диспетчер ввода-вывода, создающий специальную структуру (например в Windows это IRP), направляющий запросы к драйверу файловой системы, а та направляющая запросы к драйверу жесткого диска, который работает с контроллером, в ту очередь работающий с магнитной головкой.

**Ваш запрос передан жесткому диску, что дальше?** 
Когда ваш запрос был обработан жестким диском, он генерирует прерывание, которое обрабатывается обработчиком прерывания для данного устройства, драйвер устройства пишет данные в системную память, и уведомляет диспетчер ввода-вывода о том, что данные сохранены, но теперь нужно как-то передать данные вызывающему потоку, чтобы он мог скопировать ее результаты в буфер в адресном пространстве своего процесса.

Диспетчер ввода-вывода знает ID процесса, который запросил эти данные, он обращается к адресному пространству процесса и пишет данные из **системной памяти** в виртуальное **адресное пространство процесса** и уведомляет процесс (например, с помощью функции обратного вызова или сигнала) о том, что передача данных завершена и освобождает все связанные структуры.

**P.S** Описание работы подсистемы ввода-вывода очень хорошо описано на различных ресурсах, хотя есть давно большие статьи описывающие их на примере операционной системы, [вот здесь хорошее описание](http://www.nrjetix.com/fileadmin/doc/publications/Lectures/Lecture12-2.pdf) на основе Windows.